# How to quickly import data between similar databases in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, import

I use SQL Server.

There are 2 databases, `old` and the `new` one.

Databases relational structures are exactly the same.

The difference is:

1. Some columns in one table are missing
2. Some columns have different titles
3. Some columns in a new one are added

The question is to find the way to import data from old database to a new one.

Comment: Do you have any experience with SSIS? Your use case sounds perfect for it. In about 10 min you could set up your data transfer if you know a bit of SSIS, and maybe a couple of hours if you never worked with SSIS before. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx

Comment: Thanks you, i do not know what it is yet. I will look:)

Comment: They're 'exactly the same structure' except for the bits that are different?  I suspect 'exactly' is not exactly the best word to choose here; maybe 'very similar, containing the same sets of table names'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Import Data Wizard` in SSMS to complete the task:

[image]

It'll walk you through the steps. You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx).

Comment: +1 And you can save the workflow for later reuse, too... AND you can edit the saved package with SSIS :)

Comment: Imporing fails becatuse of autoincrementing primary keys.   Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "AuthorsId".

Comment: Against the database you're putting data into, you need to run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` before you do the import. Then `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` after it. Or vice versa--I always get that one confused.

Comment: I made that !))) Thanks really)!

Answer (score 0):

you can write a [select into query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx), but consider eric's method first. I'm only adding this as an alternative.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, e.JobTitle, a.AddressLine1, a.City, 
    sp.Name AS [State/Province], a.PostalCode
INTO dbo.EmployeeAddresses
FROM Person.Person AS c
    JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS e 
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = c.BusinessEntityID
    JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress AS bea
    ON e.BusinessEntityID = bea.BusinessEntityID
    JOIN Person.Address AS a
    ON bea.AddressID = a.AddressID
    JOIN Person.StateProvince as sp 
    ON sp.StateProvinceID = a.StateProvinceID;
GO
```

reference: msdn

with "as" statements you would need to write the column names of the destination, so that the columns match.

Comment: I understand about writing some queries but the problem is that keys are autoincrement and pasting related tables will be difficult